# Vertical align of image

Tags: html, css, alignment

I am trying to vertical align a image on my header. That is my actual code, I have it horizontall aligned into center.

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 118px;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dKLmNz6.png" alt="JPAD Logo">
  </header>
</div>
```

I tried search for a solution and could get it vertical aligned on center but then cant get it horizontal anymore with text-align:

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 118px;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dKLmNz6.png" alt="JPAD Logo">
  </header>
</div>
```

I am just really starting HTML+CSS. Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you want image center horizontally and vertically?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using Flexbox, you can add to your flex element the property `justify-content:center`

In this [css-tricks](https://css-tricks.com/centering-css-complete-guide/) article you can find a good examples about how to center elements.

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 118px;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
  width: 1024px;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">

  <header>
    <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dKLmNz6.png" alt="JPAD Logo">
  </header>


</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply add 'justify-content: center' to your flex container.

```css
header {

    background-color: blue;
    height: 118px;
    width: 1024px;
    text-align: center;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

.container{

    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
    width: 1024px;

}
img { display:block }
```

```html
<div class="container">

        <header>
            <img src="https://i.imgur.com/dKLmNz6.png" alt="JPAD Logo">
        </header>


    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to add `justify-content: center;` to header.

```css
header {
  background-color: blue;
  height: 118px;
  width: 1024px;
  text-align: center;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}
```

I hope this will help you.